# Cannot start Apache service: Access Denied

Tags: windows, apache, php-7

I'm trying to setup a new version of Apache and PHP on my Windows machine.
This is what I've got this far:

httpd.conf:

```
Loadmodule php7_module "C:/PHP/Php 7.2.8/php7apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP/Php 7.2.8/"
```

But when I try to start the service I get an error and when I look into the event viewer I see this error:

> The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>
> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 544 of F:/Apcache/Apache24.v110_xp/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/PHP/Php 7.2.8/php7apache2_4.dll into server: Access is denied.

I've set the rights to everyone on the Apache and PHP folder, but it does not work.

PS: when I change it to another PHP version (5) it does work.

Comment: I guess your rights setting did not work. Try looking at the access rights on that DLL in particular to see what the rights/owners are set to.

Comment: @halfer that did not work :( Even if I set the everyone rights to that DLL its still getting that error...

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot for two days playing around within the security section (accounts, permissions, etc.) I solved this way on Windows 10:

1. Install [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)
2. `chmod -R 770 /cygdrive/c/Applications/php/php-7.1.17/`

Honestly, I have no idea why this happens. Before trying this, I also downloaded new zip files from php web site, and Http Apache as well.